# How to use `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title` inside Vue SFC template?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I want to use `htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title` in SFC template, is that doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's doable ...but other way around

1. You can use [Environment Variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) do define your app title
2. Then you can configure `htmlWebpackPlugin` to use this ENV variable as the value for `title` option
3. At the same same time, you can use use this variable in any client side JS (be it pure JS or SFC). Note that to use it inside the template, it's necessary to assign it
   to the `data` first...

`.env file`
VUE_APP_TITLE=My App Title

`vue.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config
      .plugin('html')
      .tap(args => {
        args[0].title = process.ENV.VUE_APP_TITLE
        return args
      })
  }
}
```

`SFC`

```js
data() {
  return {
    title: process.ENV.VUE_APP_TITLE
  }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, to my surprise, I found `document.title` will do the job too XD

Answer (score 0):

`document.title` will do, [Michal's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65199153/7881859) will do too in a verbose but more strict and flexible format, see which one works best for you.